# Android Launcher Application not detecting Home key after signing with keystore

Tags: android, signing, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I am creating a Launcher Application in Android Ice Cream Sandwich.

I have 3 Activities. This is how they are declared in the manifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ActivityOne" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        >
        <intent-filter >
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

         <activity android:name=".Activitytwo"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityThree"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

    </activity>
```

After installing the apk in phone and pressing the Home Key in the System Bar takes me to "ActivityOne". This is working perfectly fine.

Then I created a key to sign the apk. Exported the project from Eclipse and signed the apk. Now pressing the Home key has no effect.

I need the application to work the same way as it was, after signing.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it.

Adding the following line in the manifest under activity tag the solved it.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".ActivityOne"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
    >
    <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove two lines

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

from your ActivityOne's

```
<intent-filter >
...
...
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: removing <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/> or
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
removes my launcher from the list of Launchers when pressing the home key.

Comment: I think it should not happen, you are doing something another mistake.

Comment: Any idea, how should i get to know what mistake am i doing ?
And also the same application is working fine without signing.. the home key stops behaving as it was after signing.

Comment: How you have made, sign-in key, can you explain/describe steps?